# How to use batch correctly with a simple Neural Network - Basic Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Ok, first of all, sorry about my English and thanks for your help.

I think I have a problem with the term "batch". I know what it means and I think understand how it works, but I don't know how to translate it into python-pytorch neural network.

I have a variable "input_train" what contains (obviously) the input data to the neural network. This is a vector of 216 values. Then, I have "label_train" what contains the expected output, all defined here:

```
f = h5py.File('./Train.h5', 'r')
input_train = f['data'][...]
label_train = f['label'][...]
f.close()

f = h5py.File('./Test.h5', 'r')
input_test = f['data'][...]
label_test = f['label'][...]
f.close()
```

I tried to print the values like "print(input_train[0])" and it works perfectly, and the values are correct.

So, now I call a function what uses this vectors and some parameters more to do the "train loop".

```
def train_loop(train, label, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch_size, (X, y) in enumerate(train, label):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
```

There is the problem. My code was written with Dataloaders, and for that reason is there that `enumerate` function. But I need to change that to don't use `enumerate`, so I have no idea how to do it. Because I really dont understand how can I say to a for bucle "ey, these are 27 inputs of my dataset, do *this* by one by". Because, I'm sure I'm wrong with it, but... where is the difference between that and putting `batch_size = 1`? I really don't understand the logic of this and how to use it correctly.

Again, thanks you all.

EDIT:

I have been working on delete the Dataloader and try to use data directly on model, and I have some archives but not the necessary ones.

Now I give to the train_loop function the data and labels separately(this last one is the correct answer that the model must predict).

```
epochs = 10
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train_loop(data_train, label_train, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    test_loop(data_test, label_test, model, loss_fn)
print("Done!")
```

And now the fucntion is defined here:

```
def train_loop(X, y, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    
    examples = len(X)
    data_foreach_example = len(X[0])
    
    print("Num examples: " + str(examples))
    print("Num data_foreach_example: " + str(data_foreach_example))
    
    size = examples
    for i in range(size):
    
        XX = np.array(X)
        yy = np.array(y)
        
        print(XX[i])
        print(yy[i])
    
        # Compute prediction and loss
        pred = model(XX[i])
        loss = loss_fn(pred, yy[i])

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
```

The prints says that I have 65000 examples to train and 216 data for each example, and that's correct.

But, my function crashes on `pred = model(XX[i])`, and here is the error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dim'

Can someone help me? -.-

Comment: Please don't post code as image, insert is as text.

Comment: Sorry @maij, it's my first post, didn't know that "rule". It's done now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a fundamental misunderstanding of how torch datasets and dataloaders work here. So I highly suggest you read [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) and [this one](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).

I fail to understand your sentence

> My code was written with Dataloaders, and for that reason is there that enumerate function

The point of the dataloader class is to not have to deal with the logic of loading the samples in batches, shuffling etc.
All you should have to do is

```
for (input_t, target_t) in dataloader:
     output_t = model(input_t)
     loss = loss_fn(output_t, target_t)
     loss.backward()
     optimizer.step()
```

The `batch_size` is a parameter that is chosen when you initialize your dataloader. It is often a value like 32 or 64. The `batch_size` is merely the number of inputs you are asking your model to process simultaneously. After each batch, the model goes through 1 backprop. So if your `batch_size` is 32, your model will have its weights modified after having seen 32 different samples.

Therefore, if you want your model to process its inputs one by one, then yeah do put the batch_size to 1, that's exactly how it works ! :)

In your code (which by the way is not exactly a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but whatever), I am not sure what `train` and `label` are supposed to be, but I'm quite convinced you don't need them (or at least not both). You only need one dataloader which will provide you tuples of `(input, target)` when you iterate over it.

After reading your edit, here are the corrections that you should make.
First, according to your prints, you have 65000 data vectors of size 216. I am going to assume that `X` is a numpy array of size (65000, 216) and not a list of arrays. Please tell me if that assumption is wrong, I'll edit.

First thing to do is to make a tensor out of it, because pytorch models work with torch tensors. It's very easy :

```
X_t = torch.from_numpy(X)
Y_t = torch.from_numpy(Y)
# Just checking you have as many labels as inputs
assert X_t.shape[0] == Y_t.shape[0]
```

Then, you need a dataset. Here all your samples are in one tensor, so you can use
`TensorDataset`:

```
dset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_t, Y_t)
```

And finally, we're gonna create the dataloader, **which you do need**. Using dataloaders makes your life much easier, as it helps you dealing with a lot of logic that you don't wna tto reimplement every time. So if you do not have a really good reason to avoid them, use them ! Here is the corresponding [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), if you want to investigate the possible arguments and what they mean.

```
loader = torch.utils.dataloader(dset, 
                                batch_size=1, # choose your batch size
                                shuffle=True) # generally a good idea
```

And now you can have your training loop :

```
for input_t, target_t in loader:
    output_t = model(input_t)
    # Do your backprop stuff after that
    ....
```

Or, with enumerate (if you want to know the batch index) :

```
for batch_index, batch in enumerate(loader):
    input_t, target_t = batch
    ...
```

Comment: Very thanks for your answer.

with that sentence, I was trying to say that when I started my code I used Dataloaders and I thought I needed to use that function because of that. 

So, now my question is... how can I put my dataset from a h5 file to a Dataloader

Comment: Or, in another case, how can I train and test my model with a dataset from a h5 file, without using Dataloader (if it is easier)

Comment: I edit the post with my last changes, could you have a look?

Thanks you, man.

Comment: I expanded my answer, I hope that covers your question :)

Comment: Very very VERY thanks, I'll try it. So much love for you.

Comment: You're very welcome. If it does solve your problem, please accept the answer